# Llamar a un JComboBox de un JFrame desde una clase

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de escritorio. Lo funcional es realizado en una clase de un paquete en especifico.
Mi código es el siguiente

```
public void cargarComboCurso()
    {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Escuela";
        String user = "user";
        String password = "password";
        String sql = "SELECT nombreCurso FROM Cursos";

        try(Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                Statement st = cn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);)
        {
            cboCurso.removeAllItems();

            while (rs.next())
            {
                cboCurso.addItem(rs.getString("nombreCurso"));
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR : ");
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
```

El problema es que mi combo **cboCurso** esta en un JFrame de otro paquete y al no poder acceder a el, el programa me arroja un error de **cannot find symbol**

Comment: ¿Por qué no envías como parámetro el `ComboBox` de tu método?

Comment: Gracias! Funciono.

Comment: agrega tu respuesta y luego márcala como aceptada :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal cual dijo Davilo, debo pasar como parametro el Combobox.

```
public void cargarComboCurso(JComboBox cboCurso)
    {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Escuela";
        String user = "user";
        String password = "password";
        String sql = "SELECT nombreCurso FROM Cursos";

        try(Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                Statement st = cn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);)
        {
            cboCurso.removeAllItems();

            while (rs.next())
            {
                cboCurso.addItem(rs.getString("nombreCurso"));
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR : ");
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
```